# How much influence for poll in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

If I implement a poll in Facebook (something someone told me I could do, haven't tried yet) then what sphere of influence does it reach?

- My Friends?
- Their Friends?
- Farther?

Comment: What do you mean by influence? People who can see the poll? People that have to live according to the poll (a.k.a. grassroots democracy)?

Comment: People who can see and __participate__ in the poll.

Comment: Which poll are you talking about ? OpinionPolls or Ad-Driven Polls ?

Comment: @phwd, Opinion Polls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a poll that allows anyone on Facebook to participate, if they know about it.  There are various ways to spread the word.  If you post it on your wall, or on the wall of a page where you are an admin, then your friends or the fans of your page can see it in their News Feed.  Others who happen to visit the page or follow a link to the poll can also participate.

Comment: So do the friends of friends see the link on their friends wall?

Comment: @Lance I am guessing it will be based on the privacy setting of the latter "friends" wall. The initial user/creator of the poll will have his X friends of influence (assuming all friends have not blocked hidden from the user feed) Then if one of the friends vote on the poll , it will depend on their option to post to their wall or not, then they have a Y set of friends that can be influenced. It should be the same as any other shared item.

Comment: @phwd, So it won't automatically show on X's wall when he does the poll, unless he chooses it too?  i.e. as an activity he participated in.

Comment: @Lance I believe so. I tried myself and created a poll with no tab addition/no posting to my wall. No activity/sign was seen on my news feed or wall.